RestSharp || Rest API Automation Testing || ExecuteAsync returning null
I am developing RestAPI automation test case using RestSharp.
I am trying sample code to test the API response. Below is my code:
var _client = new RestClient("https://reqres.in");
var request = new RestRequest("/api/users?page=2",Method.Get);
var response = await _client.ExecuteAsync(request);
Console.WriteLine("My Content : "+ response.Content);

Here ExecuteAsync always returning null. Code is not executing beyond await _client.ExecuteAsync(request); and it is not throwing any error message. Can anyone help me to correct this code?
